# How to move one page that's composed of HTML, CSS and JS from Electron-Project to Vue Project?

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I've Page with HTML, CSS and JS in my existing electron-project and I've Vue Project with electron-builder. I've moved the html to the template in vue and moved the css to the style but how to move the js?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Vue supports single-file component so you can simply move the js to script file. Add a sample file, I can help you to create a sample vue component for that.

Comment: @VaritJPatel Should I move the js code into script file over the export default?

Comment: Yes. check out this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html